# How to get downloaded models in ML Kit Translation

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I'm trying to check if a model has been downloaded for translation in ML Kit Translation.
I did not find any official documentation for this and wrote the code looking at the sample application from Google.

This code checks if among the downloaded models there is the right one:

```
public static boolean isLanguageDownloaded(String language) {
    boolean isDownloaded = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < getAvailableModels().size(); i++) {
        if (getAvailableModels().get(i).equals(language)) {
            isDownloaded = true;
        } else {
            isDownloaded = false;
        }
    }
    return isDownloaded;
}
```

This code for getting available model:

```
public static List<String> getAvailableModels() {
    List<String> availableModels = new ArrayList<>();
    getRemoteModelManager()
            .getDownloadedModels(TranslateRemoteModel.class)
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    models -> {
                        // Model downloading is complete.
                        // ...
                        for (TranslateRemoteModel model : models) {
                            availableModels.add(model.getLanguage());
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                    e -> {
                        // Model downloading failed.
                        // ...
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Model downloading failed.");
                    });
    return availableModels;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TranslateRemoteModel for the specific language and then use RemoteModelManager#isModelDownloaded API to check.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/common/model/RemoteModelManager#isModelDownloaded(com.google.mlkit.common.model.RemoteModel)

Comment: Is it possible to get specific translation model before deliver apk to end user? I want to have it within ```assets``` and tell system to use it instead of download first over wifi.